# Parse an XML File in java but doesn't containing header XML TAG ( <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>)

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, jaxb

I want to parse an XML File Which is not Containing XML Tag in the Header.
 
I Have tried DOM but it is working only if XML file Contains XML Tag In the Header.
MY XML File Structure Is Like This.
This XML I will get When I will Open Some URL.So That page contains This Below Structure.

```
<nodes>
  <node>
    <children>
       <node>
         <children>
       :
       :
       :
       :
         </children`enter code here`
       </node>
    </children>
 </node
</nodes>
```

Can Anybody suggest how Can I parse this XML?

Comment: you can try to set the encoding of the inputstream, this might help you - http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-utf-8-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

Comment: Not Helping. Can you please Suggest Any other method To parse XML Structure.

Comment: Sorry without investigation I don't know .. It is fundamental that XML has the encoding included.

Comment: I able to resolve the problem by using Simple HttpURLConnection inputstream method.